# SQL Select, sometime need 'Where' +/- 'And' sometimes need neither

Tags: sql

I have a query to construct
Sometimes it will be

**strSQL = 'Select * from  tableA'**

sometimes it will be

**strSQL = 'Select * from tableA where FieldA > x'**

sometimes it will be

**strSQL = 'Select * from  tableA where FieldB < y'**

and finally sometimes it's

**strSQL = 'Select * from  tableA where FieldA > x and FieldB < y'**

So the 'Where' can be in front of either FieldA or FieldB.
I find that this can make for convoluted conditional logic to construct the query string.
My usual 'trick' is to put in a 'Where' clause that's true for all records in the table so that fieldA and fieldB, if they are included, will always have an 'And' before them.
Something like

**strSQL = 'Select * from tableA where FieldC > 0'**

**if condition1 true**

**strSQL = strSQL +  ' and FieldA > x'**

**end if**

**if condition2 true**

**strSQL = strSQL +  ' and FieldA < B'**

**end if**

Is there a better way to achieve this other than using more conditional logic in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One trick is to use 1=1 as a condition...

```
strSQL = 'Select * from tableA where 1=1'
```

Then proceed like you already have above. This will save the DBMS having to actually check any conditions on FieldC (which will always take processing time, even if FieldC is always >0), since 1=1 will be optimised out by the query parser.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. That's perfect for what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can break out something like this to a method

```
if (first)
{
    first = false;
    return " where ";
}
else
{
    return " and ";
}
```

and call that method before the real statement in the if-blocks.

**edit:**

or break out everything to an `AppendCondition` method that also adds the condition string.

Then you call it like

```
strSQL = 'Select * from tableA'
if condition1 true
    strSQL = strSQL + AddCondition('FieldA > x')
end if
if condition2 true
    strSQL = strSQL + AddCondition('FieldA < B')
end if
```

Comment: Albin, this is probably a stupid question but how does the method know if it's the first or subsequent time it's been called by this calling sub

Comment: @jjb, it can store the `first` parameter in a class member. I assume you don't construct the query in SQL, but in another language.

Comment: Of course. Sorry I am not very well up on OOP, I was thinking procedurally in terms of a static variable that you might first clear and then increment with subsequent calls.

Answer (score 1):

In a stored procedure, I sometimes use sql like

```
select * from tableA 
where (@paramX is null or fieldA > @paramX)
and (@paramY is null or fieldB < @paramY)
```

where a `null` value means "don't check this value".